# Updating TopicsController to allow a moderator to update topics, but not create or delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in the process of creating a website similar to Reddit. I would like to allow a moderator to be able to update a topic, but not be able to create or delete topic. I'm aware that I need to update TopicsController but I'm not sure how. My main problem is that I'm not sure how to make the code specific enough to ensure that a moderator can only update; not delete or create a topic, as an admin can.

My current code looks like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_sign_in, except: :show
  before_action :authorize_user, except: [:show, :new, :create]

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post.body = params[:post][:body]
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.user= current_user
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post was saved"
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.assign_attributes(post_params)

    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
      redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@post.title}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to @post.topic
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the post."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def authorize_user
    post = Post.find(params[:id])

    unless current_user == post.user || current_user.admin?
      flash[:error] = "You must be an admin to do that."
      redirect_to [post.topic, post]
    end
  end

end
```

I've already added a moderator role to the enum role.

I apologise if this seems really basic...but it has got me stumped!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could answer with some custom solution, but it's better to use a more structured and community-reviewed approach: authorization with [cancan](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into how to use cancan!

Answer (score 0):

As [tompave noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926881/1426097) you can use cancan gem for this.
Personally I prefer [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).

In old days I used to define permissions directly in code everywhere: in controllers, in views and even models. But it's really bad practice. When your app grows, you are lost: you update a view, but you should make the same change in controller and sometimes in model too. It soon becomes absolutely unmanageable and you have no idea what your users can and cannot do.

[Pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926881/1426097), on the other hand, offers central place -- policy -- for defining what user can do. Views and controllers can then use those policies.

For example, if you need to define `Post`'s policy you simply create `app/policies/post_policy.rb` file:

```
 class PostPolicy
    attr_reader :user
    attr_reader :post

    def initialize(user, post)
      @user = user
      @post = post
    end

    def author?
      post.user == user
    end

    def update?
      author? || user.admin? || user.moderator?
    end

    def create?
      author? || user.admin?
    end

    def destroy?
      author? || user.admin?
    end

    # etc.
 end
```

Now whenever you need to check user's ability to perform action, you can simply invoke:

```
# in controller
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post
  # do whatever required
end

# in view
<% if policy(post).update? %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit Post', post_edit_path(post) %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see [Pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926881/1426097) is very easy to comprehend and it uses the same "convention over configuration" approach as Rails. At the same time it's very flexible and allows you to test virtually anything.

You will definitely need [Pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926881/1426097) or any similar gem to manage permission in your ambitious app.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I had heard of using policies before, so  will look at using Pundit!